# Making a carousel with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I made a carousel with divs that scrolls across the screen, but I'm having some weird issues where the images flash or shift suddenly when I add a gap between the cards.
I made a codepen to display the issue. If you remove the gap from the .slider-track class the janky shift is no longer there. I can't figure out what the issue is, any help would be much appreciated. Here is the codepen:

https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-zq6lly?file=/src/index.css

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I needed to set the min and max width to ensure the size of the card matches up with the animation